# How to make sure that we are writing a unique record in apache-cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to write a record in cassandra DB with a java program.But before that I wanted to make sure that record is not present in database. Whats the best solution for that?
1. Can we impose a unique constraint in table ? Or
2. Do we need to perform a read operation before write operation to make sure its unique?(But I think performing a read op will be an overhead)

Please suggest if there is better option. Can u please share a sample program.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use a lightweight transaction for this.  Example:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (login, email, name, login_count)
values ('jbellis', 'jbellis@datastax.com', 'Jonathan Ellis', 1)
IF NOT EXISTS
```

*Code taken from: [Lightweight Transactions in Cassandra 2.0](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0)*

You can also use data types that are designed for uniqueness like UUID or TIMEUUID, and generate a new one on each INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "IF NOT EXISTS" clause on inserts that uses light weight transactions. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html

Comment: Nice Chris!  I think you beat me by 18 seconds.